# easy calculus thing that i forgot

Tags: calculus

Suppose $(s_n)$ is a non- negative sequence in $R$. Suppose $m > n $, then is that true that we must have $ (s_n) \subseteq (s_m ) $ and hence we can conclude $ \inf s_n \geq \inf s_m $. but we know that $h_n = \inf_{ k \geq n } s_k $ is a non-decreasing sequence. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m>n$ then the **other** inclusion holds. That is, $$\{s_n,s_{n+1},\ldots,s_m,s_{m+1},\ldots\}\supset \{s_m,s_{m+1},\ldots\}$$

Comment: gracias CHE !!!!

Comment: De nada. =) , @DonAnselmo.

Answer (score 1):

If $m > n$, then there is no reason to assume that $(s_n) \subseteq (s_m)$. Choose $s_n = n$ for each $n$, as an example of when this could fail.

The reverse inclusion is true, however, which is consistent with the other part of your question.